# How do you write a character with multiple personalities?

Tags: characters, showing-telling, story

I have a character with multiple personalities, but the character is mute and cannot speak. He can only behave. Is there a way to show that this character has multiple personalities and is behaving differently not because the writer cannot keep his character consistent but because he has multiple personalities? How do you do this without telling, only by showing?

Comment: Try researching dissociative identity disorder (DID). WebMD in particular lists symptoms that might help you. Bear in mind that DID is a mental health disorder that deserves sensitive treatment from an author. If you want to write them well you probably need to find a friendly psychologist or look for accounts of lived experience.

Comment: You don't say what kind of character you're writing, but this article might also be worth a look: https://www.healthline.com/health-news/movie-split-harms-people-with-dissociative-identity-disorder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the obvious "do the research", which I haven't and can't tell you what exactly you should learn, an intimate way to show your character's experience is to write from their point of view.

Oh and speaking of research, don't limit yourself to medical sources. Try to find some accounts from people with DID themselves describing their life, or at least their families and friends. You're likely to find much better information that way, and less at risk of falling in the trap of objectification.

If you know someone with DID, see if you can make them your counsellor / beta-reader and correct any misconceptions.

Writing a character with a mental illness of any kind is a delicate task. You can easily paint people with that illness, or even people with mental illness in general, in negative light in the eyes of your audience, and reinforce real-world hatred. Be careful.

Answer (score 2):

Going to second the encouragement to research, including hearing people's lived experiences. It is very easy to get DSM things wrong, and often enough it leads to harmful stereotypes.

I can tell you my close experience around someone who was sometimes diagnosed with DID, sometimes diagnosed with Borderline Personality Disorder, and was overall hella traumatized.

- The personality shifts, if they existed, were either subtle or jarring in their intensity. The emotional shifts could be so sudden and expressed so wildly differently that it sometimes felt like I was experiencing a different person in the same body.
- Don't ignore what the first initial stands for: Dissociation. There were times when I went to visit this person and they didn't recognize me, yelling at me to go away. A few hours later, I learned she thought I was a delivery-person or a door-to-door salesman. We'd known each other 5 years at this point.
- Deep trauma, which looks to be the primary cause of DID, adds a complexity multiplier to everything.

That said, if you still want to tackle this, consider giving your readers cues to help them identify where this character is at in a given moment:

- For clear changes, use an adjective to describe their behavior and only use that descriptor for that person when their in the appropriate mental state.
- Show a consistent behavior. Maybe they sometimes walk really quietly, maybe other times they have tentative behavior, could be they're really nurturing at times and others they can't stand to be in the same space as the other character etc.

Last bit of advice: if this is a side character, try to stick to 2-3 identities. Main character, 3-5. The more time you spend describing a new personality is less time spent doing other things like moving your plot along, raising the tension, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For some good examples of show don't tell, I advise you to look at some superhero films where the "secret identity" aspect of the character is enforced (The Christopher Reeves Superman Films are a highlight, as Reeves portrayal of Clark Kent and Superman included several subtle changes that actually sold the concept idea that Clark's own co-workers didn't know he was also Superman.  Be hind the scenes, at least one co-actor (Annette O'Toole, who played Lana Lang in the third film) told a story how during shooting, all her scenes with Reeves as Clark were shot before all her scenes with Reeves as Superman.  On the first day of her shoots with Reeves as Superman, she said she was looking for Reeves and couldn't find him on set, and eventually went up to someone she believed was Reeve's stunt double and asked him if she saw Reeves at all that day.  The double laughed a bit and only then did she realize that the stunt double was Reeves... but because most of her prior interaction was with "Clark!Reeves" she wasn't looking for "Superman!Reeves".

Other good places to look are live action sequences where two characters are body swapped, as half the fun is watching the actors playing different characters that are familiar.  Super Sentai seems to have a "once a season" episode featuring a body swap episode, so it's not uncommon for this to get used in the Power Rangers counterpart episode, though the quality depends largely on how good the actors are.

One series that did an interesting spin on this is an early 2000s ssci-fi series called "The Dollhouse", which is about the title organization, a company that acts as a sort of escort service (while the main selling point is effectively for the perfect romantic partner for a wealthy client) the twist comes with that the escorts themselves have their personalities tailor made for them onto people who voluntarily surrender their original personality for a negotiated period of time.

In this state of zero personality, called "Dolls" the Doll speaks with little emotional inflection and is highly agreeable, and personalities are storable and changeable ala software in a computer.  When given a new personality, the doll becomes an "Active" and is convinced they are the people who they are.  Essentially, it becomes a way for the actors to show off their range, with some of them being quite convincing (on quite a few occasions, the tech has some glitches and creates some set ups where actives have sudden personality shifts) and as the show goes on.  Most of the episode actually focus on the implications of the technology that relies less on the "escort service" side of the show, and instead explore other uses (for example, the first episode the client hires the service to make an active with the personality and skill set of an extremely competent private detective, in order to help find his daughter who was kidnapped and held for ransom (it's implied that the clinet's wealth is not entirely legally earned and calling the cops would expose him to too much scrutiny.).